# C# winforms with lots of buttons with custom backgrounds and mouse hover

Tags: c#, winforms, button, hover

I have project with several hundreds of buttons, created dynamically within for-loop. I also have timer to update toolstripstatuslabel (labelClock) with current time every second:

```
static System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
...
timer.Tick += new System.EventHandler(timer_Tick);
...
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   labelClock.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Here's the problem: last clicked button will be focused, of course. So if I scroll page down, everytime timer ticks page scrolls up (or down), so the focused button becomes visible.

How can I prevent that?

Comment: maybe `SuspendLayout()` and `ResumeLayout()` will help?

Comment: *Several hundreds of buttons* sounds already wrong. What is `Page`? Problem more likely there. Sort of universal solution will be detect when scrolling begin and remove the focus, but.. see first sentence.

Comment: Doesn't make sense.  What does a timer firing and text getting set have to do with scrolling?

Comment: Well, it's kind of soundboard, one button for each soundclip. If there's a smarter way to do it than buttons, I want to know. All button is inside one Panel, so it's panel that scrolls. I think somehow timer focuses label when it's content being updated and then returns focus to one of buttons and page scrolls to show that button.

Comment: I tried to surround `labelClock.Text = ...` with `SuspendLayout();` and `ResumeLayout();`, but that does not help. Or I did it wrongly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid solution (won't work, if you need to save focus of button):

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   justAnotherButton.Focus();
   labelClock.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

You need to pass focus to another focusable control, it may be another `Button`, `TextBox`, etc. You may use button with zero `Width` and `Height`, so user won't see it.

Comment: Not stupid at all, but maybe not suitable for this, as there's no way to use arrow keys or tab to navigate because of loss of focus.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not concerned with keeping the same button focussed, set the focus to the parent form.  Although this sounds like a bit of a nightmare to deal with, and i'd look for a way not not needing hundreds of buttons!

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   formMain.Focus()
   labelClock.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a container control that extends System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl and override the ScrollToControl to return the current scroll position. Then add all your buttons to this control.

```
class MyContainer : ContainerControl
{
    protected override System.Drawing.Point ScrollToControl(Control activeControl)
    {
        return base.AutoScrollPosition;
    }
}
```